# Display NODE_ENV in command line

Tags: command-line, command, environment

I tried to show the NODE_ENV but it fails.

process.env.NODE_ENV
bash: process.env.NODE_ENV: command not found

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS or OSX you can use `echo $NODE_ENV`